# Why does call unobserve on my Intersection Observer cause isIntersecting to always read true and intersectionRatio to always equal 1?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have an intersection observer for a scroll animation. When I don't unobserve the target, it functions as expected, however, the animation occurs every time the element intersects the viewport and I want this animation to only occur once, on the initial scroll. However, when I unobserve the target, isIntersecting: true, and intersectionRatio: 1, immediately and therefor the animation fires on page load before the target even enters the viewport.

```
const emailObserverOptions = { threshold: 0, rootMargin: '0px'};
if(largeScreenQuery.matches){
    //hero join email left slide in
    let emailObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            console.log(entry)
            entry.target.classList.toggle('animate__slideInLeft')
            emailObserver.unobserve(entry.target)
        })
    }, emailObserverOptions)

    emailObserver.observe(heroEmailContactContainer);
```

I've messed around with the options, but nothing has worked yet. How can I unobserve the target and keep the desired behavior?

Comment: It's unrelated to your actual question, but I must say that I _really_ don't think you should be modifying the DOM within the `IntersectionObserver` callback (in this case, by toggling CSS class names) because that will create a feedback loop that could go-on forever. Observers are expected to not have side-effects that introduce feedback loops, as that absolutely wrecks browser rendering/layout/scripting performance. If you must have logic like this (which can be quite legitimate!) then the logic should be _idempotent_, but `toggle` is not idempotent, which is why it's a problem in this case.

Comment: _"the animation occurs every time the element intersects the viewport and I want this animation to only occur once, on the initial scroll"_ - I don't think you need _any_ scripting to accomplish this, given modern CSS features for control of transitions and animations.

Comment: @Dai Wouldn't unobserving the Intersection Observer make the logic indempotent as, despite the use of the toggle function, it's not looped but a singular event? Anyway, classList.add could replace toggle without any impact on functionality. There's no specific reason I used toggle here and it's not necessary. Do you have any suggestions how a similar scroll animation could be implemented using pure CSS?

Comment: `IntersectionObserver` will invoke its callback repeatedly (though asynchronously) on every rendered frame where a new intersection happens - it is not a one-time event. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) "The Intersection Observer API lets code register a callback function that is executed whenever an element they wish to monitor enters or exits another element (or the viewport), or when the amount by which the two intersect changes by a requested amount"

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: I completely missed your call to `unobserve` _within_ your callback (whooops!) - which invalidates most of the points I made, though given the kinda-asynchronous nature of `IntersectionObserver` I'm not entirely certain that your code is correct under all circumstances.

Comment: No problem! I'm new to using Intersection Observer, so I'm not sure it's correct either. The funny thing is that I've successfully used IO to animate other elements on my page on scroll with no problems, it's just this one that's being buggy.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a link to a page/JSFiddle/SO-Snippet that demonstrates your existing animations? I'd like to see them

Comment: Yeah! Here's the page. The animation I'm referring to is the very first one labeled 'Want us to contact you?': https://eddie-homepage.netlify.app/